# is there a mean value theorem for derivatives?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, solution-verification, mean-value-theorem

I was given the following question as part of my real analysis studies, and I'm fairly certain the question is impossible.
Prove the following:
Let *f* be a differentiable function defined on [a,b]. Then for all t in the reals, such that f'(a)<t<f'(b) there exists x∈(a,b) such that f'(x)=t.

The reason I'm struggling is this seems to be a mean value theorem related problem, however without the condition that f is twice differentiable or f' is continuous or some other similar condition, I believe that t does not have to *exist* by virtue of derivatives of functions not having to be continuous.

Help is appreciated or confirmation that the wording is wrong somehow.

Comment: It's called Darboux's theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis))

Answer (score 2):

This is not a "mean value theorem" but an "intermediate value theorem", which is a well-known fact in basic analysis.

If necessary, replace $f(x)$ by $f(x)-tx$, and thus we may assume $t=0$. Suppose $f(x)$ attains a minimum on the interval $[a, b]$ at $x=x_0$ (which exists as $f(x)$ is continuous), and we have $f'(x_0)=0$.

Comment: I don't know if I follow what you're saying. My question revolves around the idea that there's a t between the derivative at a and at b which I'm told exists, however I'm struggling because the derivative is not necessarily continuous. f is implied to be continuous, however the derivative is not necessarily continuous, I can't assume the function or the derivative takes on a min/max (where f '(x)=0) in the interval [a,b].

Comment: I'm taking the maximum/minimum of $f(x)$, not $f'(x)$, and you absolutely can because $f(x)$ is continuous.

Comment: @Ahhhhhhhhh. We use the fact that if $g$ is differentiable and if $a<x_0<b$ such that $g(x_0)=\min \{g(x): x\in [a,b]\}$ then $g'(x_0)=0.$ Consider the case $a<b$ and $f'(a)<t<f'(b).$ Let $g(x)=f(x)-tx.$ Let $x_0\in [a,b]$ such that $g(x_0)=\min \{g(x): x\in [a,b]\}. $ Now $g'(a)<0$ so $x_0\ne a$. And $g'(b)>0$ so $x_0\ne b. $ So $a<x_0<b$. So $0=g'(x_0)=f'(x_0)-t.$